# How to properly handle intersecting abstract classes in OOP?

Tags: scala, abstract-class, object-oriented-analysis

This is a question about Object-oriented Programming, and so it is not specific to Scala.  I need to write the concrete method for an abstract interface that takes in two abstract types. But I need to write it in such a way that would allow me to call methods specific to child classes.  Every simple solution that I try to follow only leads down a rabbithole of things that do not work.  If I enrich the Animal class to make it look like a Sheep, then the Pasture class cannot call Sheep-only methods. On the contrary, if I enrich the Farm class to look more like a Pasture, then the Sheep class cannot called Pasture-only methods.   This is a vicious chicken-and-egg problem. The solution to it is likely hidden in one of those textbooks about  "Programming Patterns", but I don't know where.

Your thoughts?

```
// Interface 
abstract class Farm {

}

abstract class Animal {

}

abstract class GenericSim {
  def simulate( an:Animal , fa:Farm ):Double 
}

// Instantiation
class Pasture extends Farm {
  private final val size = 23
  def getSize:Int = size 
}

class Sheep extends Animal {
  private var woolContent = 8
  def shear():Int = {
    val ret:Array[Int] = Array.ofDim[Int](1) 
    ret(0) = woolContent
    woolContent = 0
    ret(0)
  }
}

class ShepherdSimulator extends GenericSim {
  def simulate( an:Animal, fa:Farm ):Double = {
    // I need to call fa.getSize()  but that does not compile.

    // I need to call an.shear() but that does not compile.

    // What is the solution? 
    0.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `GenericSim` generic on `Animal` and `Farm`:

```
abstract class Farm
abstract class Animal

// simulations operate on an unspecified `Animal/Farm` input
abstract class GenericSim[A <: Animal, F <: Farm] {
  def simulate(animal: A, farm: F): Double
}

// specific simulations operate on specific subclasses, allowing you to access specific methods
class ShepherdSimulator extends GenericSim[Sheep, Pasture] {
  def simulate(sheep: Sheep, pasture: Pasture): Double = {
    (sheep.sheer() * pasture.getSize).toDouble
  }
}
```

---

```
val shepherd = new ShepherdSimulator
shepherd.simulate(new Sheep, new Pasture)  //  val res0: Double = 184.0


class Dog extends Animal
shepherd.simulate(new Dog, new Pasture)  // does not compile, required Sheep, found Dog
```

Comment: I think your solution is most idiomatic to scala, particularly with this use of upper type bound  `A <: Animal`  .  I might actually use it.  However, Mario Galic's answer is the correct to the specific question asked.

Answer (score 0):

With your current design you could use [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) to cast the objects from `Animal` to `Sheep` and from `Farm` to `Pasture`, for example,

```
class ShepardSimulator extends GenericSim {
  def simulate(an: Animal, fa: Farm): Double = {
    (an, fa) match {
      case (sheep: Sheep, pasture: Pasture) =>
        pasture.getSize // ok
        sheep.sheer()   // ok
        0.0

      case _ =>
        0.0
    }
  }
}
```

The key is to understand the difference between *compile-time* type of a variable and *runtime* class of the object referred to by the variable

```
val an: Animal = new Sheep 
an.sheer() // error because compiler was told `an` is just an Animal
```

Pattern matching under-the-hood casts `Animal` to `Sheep`

```
val sheep = an.asInstanceOf[Sheep]
sheep.sheer() // ok because now compiler was told animal is a Sheep
```

but explicit `asInstanceOf` is discouraged in Scala which is why pattern-matching is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the behaviour of your class hierarchy. The `Farm` class is like a marker interface which doesn't have any behaviour/property. In reality, every farm has a size, hence you could push the `getSize()` method up into the `Farm` class.

```
  // Interface
  abstract class Farm(private val size: Int) {
    def getSize: Int = size
  }
```

According to your design, the pasture `is-a` farm (inheritance). Therefore, you can get the size without knowing the subtype.

For the `Animal` the quick solution is to use typecasting. For that, as Mario Mario Galic showed in his answer, you could use pattern matching. Here's the modified Simulator.

```
  class ShephardSimulator extends GenericSim {
    def simulate(an: Animal, fa: Farm): Double = {
      // I need to call fa.getSize()  but that does not compile.
      fa.getSize
      an match {
        case s: Sheep => s.sheer()
      }
      // I need to call an.sheer() but that does not compile.

      // What is the solution?
      0.0
    }
  }
```

But if we look at with an OOP angle, you can think of `Pasture` is a part of `Farm` at least if it's a ranch. You can then compose the pasture in the farm. That means a farm `has-a` pasture. This will give greater extensibility than inheriting the farm. Because you could perhaps replace the pasture with something new when the need arises without having to subclass again (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

For the animal hierarchy, you could perhaps create a `Livestock` subclass and add a method like `produce()`. So sheep can implement it and produce wool. That means you don't have to do typecasting in your simulator class (as Scala also uses dynamic dispatch).

These are just suggestions to show you how to make use of specific behaviour but relying on the abstraction.